# showing limit doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis

show that limit doesn't exist for $f: \mathbb{R^2} \backslash \{(0,0) \} \to \mathbb{R}$ $$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^3 + y^3}
$$

would I be right in thinking I can choose points? Like say I wrtie:

let $x = 0$ and let $y \to 0$ and we get $-1$ as the limit, and similary letting $y = 0$ and $x \to 0$ then the limit would be $1$? is that all that is required?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced your function is well-defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Unless you are specifically asked to give a formal $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument, finding two paths along which the limits are different is enough.

Comment: @ClementC. I just made up the function so it may not be, I was just worried about the general method

Comment: You are right, that's all.

Comment: general method is taking paths.

Comment: is that all that is required: I would say yes.
(BTW I woudl have prefer the exercice to explicit "limit in (0,0)").

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET What do you mean?

Comment: The exercice don't mention explicitely where to evaluate the limit. (But if you made it up, forget my remark :-) )

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET apologies, yes I did, I meant for $(0,0)$ of course

Answer (score 1):

if we take the path $(t,t)$ then the function goes to $0$. but if we take the path $(2t,t)$, the function goes to $7\over 3$. so, limit doesn't exists in $0$.

Comment: Is there any thing wrong with my path?

Comment: No, nothing. Your idea works.

Comment: Your idea is ok